# some problems with npm install in angular js

Tags: angularjs

l'm a beginner in angular js. l just start to learn it. 
However l have this error when l execute npm install commande:
 npm install> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\node_modules\bufferutil

> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modu
les\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\node_modules\utf-8-validate
>   node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_
modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:356:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.7.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp
>   bower install

bower angular#~1.4.0            ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall script 'bower install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart: `npm install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-seed@0.0.0 prestart script 'npm install'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-seed package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm install
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-seed
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-seed
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A626262\WebstormProjects\FirstJsApp\npm-debug.log
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `git` and make it available on your path since both npm and bower heavily relies on git to fetch your dependencies. Fetch the latest version of git for windows [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

The installer should take care of adding git to your PATH for you.